# My code doesn't do anything

Tags: lua, roblox

```
game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:connect(function()
    for _, Player in pairs(game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()) do
      Player.Chatted:connect(function(msg)
            if string.sub(msg,1,5) == "oofergang" then 
                    Player:Kick("no no no cringe baby")
        end
    end)
  end
end)
return ''
```

How do I fix this? It doesn't do anything, no errors nothing.

Comment: I see your code has lots of callbacks, maybe you should look into [moonscript](moonscript.net) and consider using that in your project. As for line 4, it makes no sense. `string.sub(msg,1,5)` will, by definition, return something that is at most 5 characters long, so it can NEVER be `"oofergang"`, which is 9 characters long. Either compare the strings directly or look into [`string.find()` and patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be in your `string.sub()` usage. (I'm assuming this is Roblox, which I don't know much about).
The `string.sub(a, b, c)` method takes the substring of the string `a`, starting from index `b` and going to index `c`.

Your problem is that you're trying to get the substring from characters 1-5. Character 1 is the first character and character 5 is the 5th character in the string. Your `if` block is checking the first 5 characters of the player's message. The issue is that the string you're comparing it to, `"oofergang"`, is longer than 5 characters.

If the player does correctly type oofergang, the `string.sub()` that you're using will output `oofer`, which is the first 5 characters of the message. Essentially, this is what the program will see when running:

```
if "oofer" == "oofergang" then
```

`oofer` is never going to equal `oofergang`.

If you want to check if the player starts their message with `oofergang` then you should use the following `if` block instead:

```
if (string.sub(msg, 1, 9) == "oofergang") then
    --Whatever you want to do here, in your case kick the player
end
```

EDIT: As suggested, the following code allows you to find a string within another string ANYwhere, not just a the start:

```
if (string.find(msg, "oofergang")) then
    --Whatever you want to do here, in your case kick the player
end
```

Comment: or simply use `if string.find(msg, '$oofergang') then` :)